# AngularJS overriding minimum value in input type number

Tags: html, angularjs

I have been trying to set minimum value 1 for a input text box "number". And i have a button to decrement it (using angularjs). Even though i have set min="1" on clicking the button its goes below 1. How can i maintain the minimum value 1? Below is the code

https://jsfiddle.net/3uyoLqhg/2/

```
<body ng-app="">
<input ng-model="quan" ng-init="quan=5" min="1" type="number"/>
<button ng-click="quan=quan-1">minus</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input [min directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) is for validation, not for restricting model value. Chrome does have these tiny up and down arrows appear inside the right edge of the input box that respects `min` attribute, but that's about it. You just have to write your own restriction logic like

```
<button ng-click="quan = quan > 1 ? quan - 1 : quan">minus</button>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zd3h5nd6/)

Answer (score 0):

If your min is going to be `1` then you can use short circuit evaluation

```
 <button ng-click="quan=(quan-1) || 1">minus</button>
```